# An easy way to deploy Django without Internet access?

Tags: python, django, deployment

What I have is development version of intranet site developed with Django and some external libraries placed in virtualenv. It runs fine and I can easily set up virtualenv with the same parameters (using pip) on any computer with internet connection. But, unfortunately it needs to be deployed on computer without :( Any way to deal with this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<s>You can [create PIP bundle](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/index.html#bundles).</s>

Update: pip bundle has been deprecated, and removed from PIP since version 1.5

With PIP 1.5 you should instead create local cache of the packages.

1. download packages: `pip install --download <DIR> -r requirements.txt`
2. use them: `pip install  --no-index --find-links=<DIR> -r requirements.txt`

Alternative is to use [`wheel`](http://wheel.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) packages:

1. install `wheel` if you don't have it already `pip install wheel`
2. download packages: `pip wheel --wheel-dir=<DIR> -r requirements.txt`
3. use them: `pip install --use-wheel --no-index --find-links=<DIR> -r requirements.txt`

Comment: seems URL has changed a tiny bit: http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/user_guide.html#fast-local-installs

Comment: @lab419: resulted to me more complex than just URL change, thanks for noticing thou.