# Install Django on machine without internet access

Tags: python, django, installation

I have VM with Win7. Python is running in Version 2.7. Now I want to install Django. I download django as tar.gz from official website. Then I move the file to VM and try to install with...

```
C:\Users\TestUser>pip install D:\Django-1.10.5.tar.gz
```

But it not work. I get this output:

```
Processing d:\django-1.10.5.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: Django
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for Django
  Stored in directory: C:\Users\TestUser\AppData\Local\pip\Cache\wheels\78\62\f
a\c970671f67ec027f6445dc8ed9a3155e774c0e75ca63dd291b
Successfully built Django
Installing collected packages: Django
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\TestUser\Programm\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", lin
e 223, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "D:\TestUser\Programm\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py"
, line 298, in run
    root=options.root_path,
  File "D:\TestUser\Programm\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", lin
e 622, in install
    **kwargs
  File "D:\TestUser\Programm\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py",
 line 808, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root)
  File "D:\TestUser\Programm\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py",
 line 1003, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "D:\TestUser\Programm\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 339,
 in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "D:\TestUser\Programm\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 323,
 in clobber
    os.utime(destfile, (st.st_atime, st.st_mtime))
WindowsError: [Error 87] Falscher Parameter: 'D:\\TestUser\\Programm\\Python27\\
Lib\\site-packages\\django\\shortcuts.py'
```

Also the following comand not work:

```
D:\dist\Django-1.10.5>python setup.py install
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing requirements to Django.egg-info\requires.txt
writing Django.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to Django.egg-info\top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to Django.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
writing entry points to Django.egg-info\entry_points.txt
reading manifest file 'Django.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
no previously-included directories found matching 'django\contrib\admin\bin'
warning: no previously-included files matching '__pycache__' found anywhere in
istribution
writing manifest file 'Django.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build\bdist.win32\egg
running install_lib
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib
creating build\lib\django
copying django\shortcuts.py -> build\lib\django
error: [Error 87] Falscher Parameter: 'build\\lib\\django\\shortcuts.py'
```

What's wrong? Thanks.
Eric

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I install Django as offline in Windows 7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35144184/can-i-install-django-as-offline-in-windows-7)

Comment: No, because I know how to install offline (see my command). But it don't work. Also, the other topic delivers no answer.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34704163/installing-django-and-related-packages-on-an-offline-computer

Comment: It is duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5858567/an-easy-way-to-deploy-django-without-internet-access